# Facebook Custom Audience pixel on SinglePageApplication SPA

Tags: facebook, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a SinglePageApplication built with AngularJs. I want too add Facebook Custom Audience tracking pixel globally and update it manually every time user changes page (url).

Is it possible and if so, how?

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-website-faq/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by loading _fbq object:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
        if (!_fbq.loaded) {
            var fbds = document.createElement('script');
            fbds.async = true;
            fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
            _fbq.loaded = true;
        }
        _fbq.push(['addPixelId', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']);
    })();
    //Notice removed 'PixelInitialized' call.
</script>
```

and then calling 'PixelInitialized' event every time page changes.

```
$window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
```

Since then facebook correctly tracks my audiences.

Comment: When exactly do you call 'PixelInitialized'? On state change?

Comment: Also, this will fire `PixelInitialized ` multiple times. On every state change.

Comment: I call it on every url change. You could do it in $routeChangeSuccess

Comment: I did that but the pixel helper chrome extension says that I am calling event 'pixelinitialized' multiple times even though the url changes.

Comment: Yes, because url changes, but page doesn't reload. Just ignore that warning :)

Comment: Cool.. Also, for me, the url part after # is being ignored on analytics dashboard. Is that the correct behavior?

Comment: That's probably facebook ignoring it. I don't use hashbang urls (#). I think it's save to enable html5mode (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location). Most browsers support it these days.

Comment: You could try executing same code in router subscription: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I'm doing that seems to be working so far:

In my index.html file I removed the PageView function and commented out the pixel itself, as shown below.

```
<head>
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

  fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
//fbq('track', "PageView");
</script>
<!--<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"-->
               <!--src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"-->
</noscript>-->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
</head>
```

Then, I configure my app as follows...

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$windowProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $windowProvider) {
var $window = $windowProvider.$get();
```

Now, for each state change, I use the onEnter and onExit to fire off the "events" I want to capture:

```
.state('foo.bar', {
        url:'/bar',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'templateCtrl',
        onEnter: function(){
            $window.fbq('track', "Page1Enter");
        },
        onExit: function(){
            $window.fbq('track', "Page1Exit");
        }
    })
```

I'm guessing that, if I wanted to, I could simply move any `fbq('track', "PageView");` code into a controller. For my use case, though, tracking from state changes works perfectly for monitoring flow from within my app.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: What if I need to set pixel ID dynamically based on endpooints in the index.html? As two binding seems not to work there right?

Answer (score 1):

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    // initialize facebook pixel code
    fbq('init', {SET-YOUR-ID}); // <-- replace {SET-YOUR-ID} with your facebook pixel convesion id 
    // disabled automatic push state for single web application
    fbq.disablePushState = true;
    // then call manually track PageView event
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
```

Into Single Page Application(SPA) you must disabled automatic listen on push State, pop State and windows history as Facebook pixel library by default hook into windows.history and push/pop state.

according to [@lari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144118/1908296) answer [about another related question to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36559028/1908296) and [Josh's Post blog](https://www.andjosh.com/2016/05/31/calming-facebooks-eager-pixels/)