# What is the difference between Rx.Observable subscribe and forEach

Tags: rxjs

After creating an Observable like so

```
var source = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {...});
```

What is the difference between **subscribe**

```
source.subscribe(function(x) {});
```

and **forEach**

```
source.forEach(function(x) {});
```

Answer (score 67):

In the [ES7 spec](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-observable), which [RxJS 5.0](http://reactivex.io/RxJS/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) follows (but RxJS 4.0 does not), the two are NOT the same.

**subscribe**

```
public subscribe(observerOrNext: Observer | Function, error: Function, complete: Function): Subscription
```

`Observable.subscribe` is where you will do most of your true Observable handling. It returns a subscription token, which you can use to cancel your subscription. This is important when you do not know the duration of the events/sequence you have subscribed to, or if you may need to stop listening before a known duration.

**forEach**

```
public forEach(next: Function, PromiseCtor?: PromiseConstructor): Promise
```

`Observable.forEach` returns a promise that will either resolve or reject when the Observable completes or errors. It is intended to clarify situations where you are processing an observable sequence of bounded/finite duration in a more 'synchronous' manner, such as collating all the incoming values and then presenting once, by handling the promise.

Effectively, you can act on each value, as well as error and completion events either way. So the most significant functional difference is the inability to cancel a promise.

Comment: "In the ES7 spec, which RxJS 5.0 follows (but RxJS 4.0 does not), the two are NOT the same." 

It's very important to notice that specifications change over time. Which is very annoying, so something that it's correct now, maybe it wasn't in the past or won't be in the future.

So the correct answer has always to specify for which version of what (and this one does).

Comment: With forEach do we need to unsubscribe or does it handles by itself?

Comment: @SamiullahKhan : Your question requires more complexity than yes/no to answer. `forEach` subscribes internally, and then returns a promise; with that promise you have no way to unsubscribe. However, you also have no way to cancel, so you probably assume it will complete or fail without your intervention. The conventional design expectation of observable libraries is that `Unsubscribe` happens automatically upon either `Complete` or `Error`. Therefore, if `forEach` conceptually works for you, then no, you don't need to unsubscribe. `forEach` does not `Unsubscribe` but `Complete` and `Error` do.

Comment: So, as I understand, `forEach` is useful for something like `await obs.forEach(doSomething)`, where your method will finish after the observable completes. On the other hand, when the lifetime of the observer may be shorter than the one of the observable, you'll use `.subscribe()` with the corresponding `.unsubscribe()`.

Answer (score 4):

I just review the latest code available, technically the code of foreach is actually calling subscribe in RxScala, RxJS, and RxJava. It doesn't seems a big different. They now have a return type allowing user to have an way for stopping a subscription or similar.

When I work on the RxJava earlier version, the subscribe has a subscription return, and forEach is just a void. Which you may see some different answer due to the changes.

```
/**
 * Subscribes to the [[Observable]] and receives notifications for each element.
 *
 * Alias to `subscribe(T => Unit)`.
 *
 * $noDefaultScheduler
 *  
 * @param onNext function to execute for each item.
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if `onNext` is null
 * @throws rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException if the [[Observable]] tries to call `onError`
 * @since 0.19
 * @see <a href="http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html">ReactiveX operators documentation: Subscribe</a>
 */
def foreach(onNext: T => Unit): Unit = {
    asJavaObservable.subscribe(onNext)
 }

def subscribe(onNext: T => Unit): Subscription = {
    asJavaObservable.subscribe(scalaFunction1ProducingUnitToAction1(onNext))
}

/**
 *  Subscribes an o to the observable sequence.
 *  @param {Mixed} [oOrOnNext] The object that is to receive notifications or an action to invoke for each element in the observable sequence.
 *  @param {Function} [onError] Action to invoke upon exceptional termination of the observable sequence.
 *  @param {Function} [onCompleted] Action to invoke upon graceful termination of the observable sequence.
 *  @returns {Disposable} A disposable handling the subscriptions and unsubscriptions.
 */
observableProto.subscribe = observableProto.forEach = function (oOrOnNext, onError, onCompleted) {
  return this._subscribe(typeof oOrOnNext === 'object' ?
    oOrOnNext :
    observerCreate(oOrOnNext, onError, onCompleted));
};

/**
 * Subscribes to the {@link Observable} and receives notifications for each element.
 * <p>
 * Alias to {@link #subscribe(Action1)}
 * <dl>
 *  <dt><b>Scheduler:</b></dt>
 *  <dd>{@code forEach} does not operate by default on a particular {@link Scheduler}.</dd>
 * </dl>
 * 
 * @param onNext
 *            {@link Action1} to execute for each item.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if {@code onNext} is null
 * @throws OnErrorNotImplementedException
 *             if the Observable calls {@code onError}
 * @see <a href="http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html">ReactiveX operators documentation: Subscribe</a>
 */
public final void forEach(final Action1<? super T> onNext) {
    subscribe(onNext);
}

public final Disposable forEach(Consumer<? super T> onNext) {
    return subscribe(onNext);
}
```

Comment: Since the forEach does not return the result of subscribe, the difference is the return value. This means you can not cancle a "subscription" started by calling forEach.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Its the part they have updated on the recent code, and I just update my answer accordingly.