# ActivatedRoute.params forEach method vs subscribe method

Tags: angular, routes

I know that both of `ActivatedRoute.params.forEach` and `ActivatedRoute.params.subscribe` will return the paramaters set into route config.

Into my configuration for example:

```
{ path: 'auditioning/:casterType/list',  component: AuditionComponent }
```

When I check the parameters I do this:

```
this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (params) => {
       console.log(params) // return object of parameters
    }
);
```

Or

```
this._activatedRoute.params.forEach(
        (params) => {
           console.log(params) // return object of parameters
        }
    );
```

**When I should use `forEach` or `subscribe` when getting params into `path` because both of them return the result what I want?**

**What is the best practice?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Rx.Observable subscribe and forEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533197/what-is-the-difference-between-rx-observable-subscribe-and-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the **[Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#params-anchor)** it is of type Observable,

So I always use the

```
this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (params) => {
       console.log(params) // return object of parameters
    }
);
```

I hate using forEach on observables as it might cause a lot of troubles.