# Is there a benefit to using forEach instead of subscribe with a keyboard input event observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm trying to find confirmation if I should prefer to use `.forEach` instead of `.subscribe` when I want to listen in on Angular's `FormControl.valueChanges` observable. [FormControl API](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)

In Angular's Documentation for forms they use `.forEach` without really explaining why and say you don't really need to understand it. [Document Link](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#observe-control-changes)

I also know from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399823/3859456) that `.forEach` will bundle a sort of finite duration of events/incoming values into a promise.

So I tried to test both `.forEach` and  `.subscribe` myself thinking that  `.forEach` will be more performant in bundling keyboard input events if the user were to type monkey crazy on it.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
}
private createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
    });
}

private forEach = this.myForm.get('name').valueChanges.forEach(value => {
  console.log(value, 'forEach');
});

private subscription = this.myForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value, 'subscribe');
});
```

In my test manually typing fast in the html input did not bundle `.forEach` values as I expected. Instead both `.subscribe` and `.forEach` emited values one character at a time.

Is there any benefit to `.forEach` over `.subscribe` in this situation and how can I create a test that can show the difference if there is a benefit to using `.forEach` over `.subscribe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's often possible to use both of them you need to be aware that `forEach` works similarly to Promises that emit multiple values.

This also means you can't unsubscribe from `forEach` so with Observables that never complete you are very likely to create memory leaks (like `valueChanges` or Router events).

I'm not sure if `valueChanges` ever completes to be honest. I checked the source code at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.0/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L636-L867 and they never send the `complete` notification. I didn't find any test that makes sure proper `complete` notification is sent (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.x/packages/forms/test/form_control_spec.ts). So I don't know why they are using `forEach` in Angular docs. I think they should be using `subscribe` instead.

I don't even see why would `valueChanges` complete anyway. Only when you destroy the form but you don't control this yourself.

If you want to test anything you need to know what you expect as a result. I don't understand what benefits you want to see after writing tests.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Regarding the test, I also can't know yet what I want to test since I'm still trying to figure out if there was even a benefit in the first place. Your answer helped me decide to use `.subscribe` instead so I can have more control over the subscription.

Comment: I'll post and issue on Angular's github regarding using `forEach`. I'm really curious whether there's something I don't see and it's really better than `subscribe()` when using in combination with `valueChanges`.

Comment: @martin, did you create the issue, can you please provide us the link, please?