# How to write jasmine.createSpyObject(...) for router.events.forEach

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to write a test case for one of the components in an application the constructor is as follows.

```
  constructor(private router: Router,
              public dialog: MatDialog,
              private tlsApiService: TlsApiService,
              private ncCutterSheetApiService: NcCutterSheetApiService,
              ) {
                this.outEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();

                router.events.forEach((event) => {
                  if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                    if(this.dialogRef){
                      this.dialogRef.close()
                    }
                  }
                  
                  // NavigationEnd
                  // NavigationCancel
                  // NavigationError
                  // RoutesRecognized
                });
              }
```

when I try to write a mock of the router using jasmine.createSpyObj I am getting this message.

**TypeError: router.events.forEach is not a function**

I have tried the following ways of creating the spyObject

```
    mockRouter = jasmine.createSpyObj(['events',['forEach']]);

    mockRouter = jasmine.createSpyObj('events',['forEach']);

    mockRouter = jasmine.createSpyObj(['events','forEach']);
```

I keep getting the same error. I have done google searches trying to find what I need and so far I have not found what I am looking for to get this to work.  Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: try: `const mockRouter = { events: jasmine.createSpyObj('events', ['forEach']) };`

Comment: Thank you Poul, that fixed my issue.

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted it as an answer. For future readers and e-points ;)

Answer (score 1):

To create a spy for the events object on the router you need to first create an object, and create your spy on that object:

```
const mockRouter = { events: jasmine.createSpyObj('events', ['forEach']) };
```

How ever, best would be to rewrite your code like this:

```
router.events.pipe(
  filter((event): event is NavigationStart => event instanceof NavigationStart)
).subscribe((start) => {
  this.dialogRef?.close()
});
```

which you can then listen to `pipe`:

```
const mockRouter = { events: jasmine.createSpyObj('events', ['pipe']) };
```

However, perhaps it's more in place to listen to the subscribe :) but that's up to you

Comment: @Akhil you are absolutely right, `forEach` is something legacy. I never use it anymore, especially because it returns a `Promise` and you are mixing two things then. I'll update my answer a bit

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Appreciate the different approaches you've provided in your answer.... Upvoted 

Comment: If I was the only person working on this application re-writing to get rid of the forEach would be easy and I would have done so. I am working with a team and this is not the only place where a forEach is used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to rewrite your code in your TS with `router.events.subsribe()` instead of `router.events.forEach()`.

The detailed reason can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177768/is-there-a-benefit-to-using-foreach-instead-of-subscribe-with-a-keyboard-input-e)

If you are willing to rewrite, then please go ahead and modify your TS like ::

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
 if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
 ...
 }

 if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
 ...
 }

);
```

and, in your spec.ts ::

```
class MockRouter {
  public ne = new NavigationEnd(0, '_url', '_url_after_redirects');

  public ns = new NavigationStart(0, 'url');

  public events = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(this.ne);
    observer.next(this.ns);
    observer.complete();
  });
}
```

Finally,

```
providers: [{provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter]
```