# Is it necessary to think about unsubscribe with observable.forEach (subscribed internally by rxjs)

Tags: angular, rxjs

the Angular form valueChanges observable can be used in this form:

```
form.valueChanges.forEach((v)=>console.log(v))
```

In this case, do I need to worry about unsubscribing? with forEach, there is no explicit subscribe() in my code. Is that means rx.js or angular will handle the unsubscribe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Rx.Observable subscribe and forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533197/what-is-the-difference-between-rx-observable-subscribe-and-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

**forEach** subscribes internally, and then returns a promise.

With that promise you have no way to unsubscribe.