# Angular2: How to find out what was previous page url when using angular2 routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am developing an angular2 app and I use router.
I am in a page /myapp/signup. after signup I navigate the use to /myapp/login. /myapp/login can also be navigated from my home page which is /myapp. So now, when the user users /myapp/login I go back. This can be done by using location.back(). But I dont want to go back when the user is coming from /myapp/signup. So I should check if the user is coming from /myapp/signup and if so, I want to direct it to somewhere else.
How can I know the previous url so that I direct the user to a specific state based on that ?

Comment: Take look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74887593/6666348

Answer (score 25):

The `pairwise` operator allows to get the current together with the previous value

**update**

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pairwise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.events
        .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .pairwise().subscribe((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
}
```

See also [How to detect a route change in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657)

**original (super old)**

Inject `Router` and subscribe to events and store them for later reference

```ts
constructor(private _router: Router) {
  this._router.subscribe(route => {
    this.nextRoute ...
    this.prevRoute ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Updated. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657

Comment: This approach is helping me to re-write a non-standard breadcrumb.  Very handy!

Comment: I had to go to previous page after certain operation. This solved the problem with minimal code. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work if you need the previousUrl on a route component that just loaded, this needs two navigation events while in the same component. Does the Router/ActivatedRoute not store the previous url anywhere?

Comment: When I tried it last time it worked for me. Can you reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: in angular 5 -> "property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<event>' "

Comment: That's not related to Angular, only to RXJS. https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#filter Check that you have the required imports

Comment: This looks like a big out of memory leak problem at some moment. Since if I log `e` I get an increasing/appending list of current and previous links.. No way this is a stable approach.

Comment: @danger89 can't reproduce https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-cr5ulv

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You are right. You couldn't add this to some sub-module, but only to AppComponent. That was my flaw. However, how to use the last url within another module/component?

Comment: Ps. I'm now using a service for this, which I think is a good practice. Moreover, what is the type of `e` when I use the **update** example above? Currently hacking it like so: ```const prev = <NavigationEnd>e[0]
      const cur = <NavigationEnd>e[1]
      console.log('Previous url' + prev.url)
      console.log('Previous url' + cur.url)```

Comment: 2 navigation events are needed for pairwise to work. For example, if I open page1 and go to page2, when I examine the value on page2 there is nothing, this is because only one event has been emitted, if I go from page2 to page3 and examine the value on page3 this is when pairwise outputs the value. how could i solve this?

Comment: You can use startWith to make the stream emit on first navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would do it this way:

```
@Injectable() // do not forget to register this class as a provider
export class PreviousRouteRecorder implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
  canDeactivate(component: any): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    localStorage.setItem('previousRoute', this.router.url);
    return true;
  }
}

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first',
    component: FirstComponent,
    canDeactivate: [PreviousRouteRecorder]},
  {
    path: 'second',
    component: SecondComponent
  }
];

export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('previousRoute'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 6 updated code for getting previous url as string.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor (
        public router: Router
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events
            .pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
                pairwise()
            ).subscribe((e: any) => {
                console.log(e[0].urlAfterRedirects); // previous url
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `document.referrer`

```
if(document.referrer !== '/myapp/signup'){
    location.back()
}
```

Comment: Not working when I test it. document.referer returns nothing in all the cases. Maybe it doesnt behave the this way when in angular2 ?

Comment: Im using angular2 router.navigate to navigate to the new state!

Comment: Aha, so you are not coming from another url? The url isn't changing?

Comment: I am coming from another URL. I am in localhost/myapp/signup and I navigate to /myapp/login  USING angular Router.navigate method. For some reason document referer is always empty regardless of where I am coming from to /myapp/login. I m thinking angular should has this functionality to know which url I am coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe leverage the [`OnActivate` phase](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html) with the `routerOnActivate` method that gives you access to the previous url and the current one.

```
routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
  console.log(`Finished navigating from "${prev ? prev.urlPath : 'null'}" to "${next.urlPath}"`);
}
```

Comment: this worked well for me, cheers, just need to make sure ComponentInstruction is imported :) 
`import {Router, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';`

Comment: This is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation with the pairwise will not work if the user doesn't trigger navigation event at least two times and may cause a small bug.

page 1 -> page 2
---> navigation event triggered, but event Observable has only 1 value and thus pairwise does not emit
---> User cannot go back to page 1

page 2 -> page 3
--> event Observable now has 2 elements and pairwise emits

I wonder if there is a workaround?

Comment: Read the help, don't post questions and comments as answers. If you want to comment other answer and you can't do it, try to level up first.

Comment: @PhoneixS Maybe you should read the help to understand that not everyone can post a comment. Such annoyance receiving notifications from you for nothing

Comment: I was only reporting the rules of this site. I have also started from 1 reputation without comments so I know how it is and this does not exempt from complying with the rules.

Comment: I am having the same problem, the pairwise operator does not work as expected as commented by @Hou. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the previous url using a auth guard and set the previous url in any were of the application.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot) {
                this.commonService.prevRouter = this.router.url;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

 private currentLocation;
 constructor(private location: Location){
    this.currentLocation = this.location.path();  
   }

ngAfterViewInit() {
 let instance = this;
 this.router.parent.subscribe(() => {            
        if (instance.currentLocation != instance.location.path()) {
             console.log("previous -> "+instance.currentLocation+" != next -> "+instance.location.path());             
        }else{
            console.log("previous -> "+instance.currentLocation+" == next -> "+instance.location.path());
        }
    });
}
```