# Does switchMap to Angular HTTP-Request needs unsubscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription, httpservice, switchmap

I am wondering if I have to unsubscribe my subscription in the following case. I create an observable using `combineLatest` of the two angular observables `route.params` and `route.queryParams`.
To use them as parameters within an http request I call `switchMap` and return the http request's observable.
Then I describe to this observable.

Now I am wondering if I have to take care of the subscription.
Usually I do not since the observable returned by angular's http service completes after first value emit.

In my current case I am not sure since the original observable was created by calling `combineLatest`.

```
// Somewhere within my component.

const subscription = combineLatest(this.route.params, this.route.queryParams).pipe(
  switchMap(([params, queryParams]: [Params, Params]) => this.http.get<number>(`query/path/${params.id}/${queryParams.type}`)
).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to unsubscribe. This hasn't anything to do with your switch map, but with your combineLatests and its parameters.

`combineLastest` will emit the lastest value of each observerable. Both `this.route.params` and `this.route.queryParams` will keep emitting values as your route changes. Therefore also your `combineLatest` will keep emitting values.

Answer (score 2):

`switchMap` does not change anything with regards to unsubscribing.

But the fact that you are combining `activatedRoute`'s streams does. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138081/do-i-have-to-unsubscribe-from-activatedroute-e-g-params-observables).

> When subscribing to an observable in a component, you almost always arrange to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.
>   There are a few exceptional observables where this is not necessary. The ActivatedRoute observables are among the exceptions.
>   The ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer needed and the injected ActivatedRoute dies with it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that !