# Angular 7: Refresh the page on params change

Tags: angular, routes

I have created the app in Angular 7. In the navigation part, when the params change in browser url, page is not refreshing.

ex:

User clicked on disciplines menu item and the page url looks like
`http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines`

user clicked on table row item in the disciplines page, url looks like
`http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1150`

when user again click on the disciplines menu item, url is changing correctly in browser url like  `http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines` but the page is not refreshing/reloaded.

Expert advise please?

Comment: Can you share your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ActivatedRoute from the Angular Router :

> import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

You just then have to inject it in your component's constructor:

> constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

In your ngOnInit you'll just have to subscribe to the changes that happen on the route:

> this.routeSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((param: any) => {
>         this.id = param['disciplineId'];
>         this.yourSpecialFunction();
> });

**IMPORTANT:** I always create a subscriber property:

> `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';`
>  
>   ...
>   ...
>   export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
>   private routeSubscription: Subscription

Make sure component implement OnDestroy and in the ngOnDestroy() method:

> ngOnDestroy() {
>       this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
>     }

You have to unsubscribe to every subscription in your app to avoid memory leaks.

For more subscription information, please refer to this Tomas Trajan's article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe the ActivatedRoute observable, but it's a good practice to have. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138081/do-i-have-to-unsubscribe-from-activatedroute-e-g-params-observables