# Should i unsubscribe from ActivatedRoute when calling subscribe method within a Router subscription?

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute, rxjs-subscriptions

I've read that normally you don't have to unsubscribe from `Router` or `ActivatedRoute` explicitly because:

> The ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router
> itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer
> needed and the injected ActivatedRoute dies with it.

source: [Do I have to unsubscribe from ActivatedRoute (e.g. params) observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138081/do-i-have-to-unsubscribe-from-activatedroute-e-g-params-observables)

However I am calling `subscribe()` on `ActivatedRoute.firstChild.paramMap` repeatedly in the parent component `app.component`. This component is only destroyed when the user navigates away from the web application or closes the website so i'm worried that those `paramMap` subscriptions might remain active the entire time.

The subscription calls are made within a `Router.events` subscription and it looks like this:

```
this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
  .pipe(
    tap((event) => { 
      switch (true) {
        case event instanceof NavigationStart: { 
          setTimeout(() => this.showChildComponentLoading = true);
          break;
        }

        case event instanceof NavigationEnd:{
          this.activatedRoute.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
          if(paramMap.has('mode')){
              let newWebAppMode:string = paramMap.get('mode');
              if(this.dataStoreService.isValidWebAppMode(newWebAppMode) && newWebAppMode !== this.dataStoreService.currentAppMode)
                  this.saveToLocalStorage.next([DataType.WEB_APP_MODE, newWebAppMode]); 
          }
        });
//other code
```

Every time someone navigates to another component/page `activatedRoute.firstChild.paramMap` is subscribed to again. I have to do this inside the router subscription and only when the event is an instance of `NavigationEnd` because before that the url parameters are not yet available.

My question is, what happens to those subscriptions? Do they unsubscribe automatically or do i need to unsubscribe each new one manually? If the latter is the case, how can i do that effectively?

Some of you may advice me to use `activatedRoute.firstChild.snapshot.paramMap.myParameter` because then i don't have to subscribe to anything. However, `snapshot` does not work when the url parameter changes while the same component is reused. So i can't use that.

Thank you

Comment: when you navigate away, everything is cleared, nothing stays 'subscribed', because the entire js context is disposed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does look like a potential memory leak: on every `NavigationEnd` a new subscription is born, so that you have potentially unlimited number of identical observers of the same stream (and `activatedRoute.firstChild.paramMap` emits indefinitely). You can verify that by putting a simple `console.log(new Date())` inside the subscription.

I believe `switchMap` is your friend here (it automatically unsubscribes from the old stream when subscribing to a new one). Sth like

```
this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    switchMap(() => this.activatedRoute.firstChild.paramMap),
    filter(paramMap => paramMap.has('mode')),
    map(paramMap => paramMap.get('mode')),
    filter(newMode => this.dataStoreService.isValidWebAppMode(newMode) && 
        newMode !== this.dataStoreService.currentAppMode),
).subscribe(newMode => this.saveToLocalStorage.next([DataType.WEB_APP_MODE, newMode]);
```

BTW, don't you need to guard against `this.activatedRoute.firstChild` being null?

Comment: no i don't have to guard against that. The parent component always displays a child component. I found out that i don't have to unsubscribe because it reuses the same ActivatedRoute instance under the hood. I found this out when i added `pipe(first())`. `first()` will allow ActivatedRoute to emit one value only and after that it automatically completes. That means ActivatedRoute will no longer work afterwards. So its best not to unsubscribe manually

Answer (score 0):

No Need of unsubscribe in these cases

1. In case of HttpClient calls because the observable emit one value (success or error) and complete automatically.
2. In case or ActivatedRoute subscription because the Router will destroy it when the component is destroyed automatically
3. use of Async pipe

Comment: `the Router will destroy it when the component` yes, but the `app.component` isen't destroyed until the browser is closed or the user navigates away from the website. That means that those subscriptions could stay active in memory until the user stops browsing the website. But i'm not sure about this hence the question.