# Is unsubscribing handled automatically for Angular/RxJS Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have heard that Angular automatically handles unsubscription for it's own Observables and therefore there is no need for manual unsubscription from an observable.

I was left with the impression that I should unsubscribe from an Observable if it is a custom one. I am looking for an explanation on this and where am I mistaken.

Example:

```
constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
            this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
                if (params.id) {
                    this.show(params.id);
                }
            });
    }
```

vs.

```
constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
            this._route.queryParams.pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)).subscribe(params => {
                if (params.id) {
                    this.show(params.id);
                }
            });
    }
```

I am using ActivatedRoute's queryParams observable and I was left with the impression that here Angular automatically handles the unsubscription and I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: angualr automatically cleans up route observable from ActivetedRoute as queryParams. these are part of the route lifecycle which is managed by angular's router,  angular authomatically unsbscribe when the componant is destroyed

Comment: @Kristian As a best practice just unsubscribe it depends on your scenario if it gets unsubscribed or not ( [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138081/do-i-have-to-unsubscribe-from-activatedroute-e-g-params-observables), btw do check this out [takeUntilDestroyed](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a manual `subscribe` like in your examples you should also do an unsubscribe.  The `takeUntil` idiom you showed where `_unsubscribeAll` is completed in the teardown is very common.

Angular does automatic unsubscriptions when using `async` pipes, so if you render an `Observable` in your html template with something like `myObs | async` you do not need this.