# How to get the route name of component from which i navigate from?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

In my Angular 2 (final) application, I need to get the router name from which I navigated from.

For Example: If I navigate from this url

`'http://localhost:3000/#/home'` to `'http://localhost:3000/#/about-us'`

(i.e) From home component to about us component.

Now, my problem is how to get the route name of component, in short how to get the route name from where I navigated from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548895/6554634 here you can find

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I think this would give the current route name, but how to get the route name from where i navigated from.

Comment: I didn't test but try to print `val` in that answer. It will have the current and previous routes I think

Comment: Ya...Checked...getting current route name..

Comment: Have tried to printing `val instanceof NavigationEnd`? Please make a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to route changes event in both parent & child routes and keep the currentUrl, to use it when the route changes next time.

```
    previousUrl: string;
    constructor(router: Router) {
      router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(e => {
          this.previousUrl = e.url;
      });
    }
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41039092/6274852) & [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657)