# Get previous route path Angular 4

Tags: angular

everyone.
I got the issue with the getting the previous path, which i came from to current one.
I found lots of examples that to get back to previous path I need `location.back()`.

Is there is another way how to get the url for previous path? 
Thank you.

Comment: you can make use of a shared service which will hook on to the router outlet event and save it in a array of shared services . more on [shared services](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine previous page URL in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular2)