# Angular: Location back history

Tags: angular, typescript, location, back

I have a form with a "back" button. When the user presses the back button, the script goes to the previous page:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

// In a place in La Mancha, whose name I do not want to remember...
this.location.back();
```

But, what happens when the user directly enters the url in the address bar? In those cases the application goes back to the Browser's homepage. I would like something like this:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

// In a place in La Mancha, whose name I do not want to remember...
if (this.location.history.length > 0) {
    this.location.back();
} else {
    this.router.navigate(['/home');
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 22):

You could check the history with `window.history.length`. Therefore your function would look like

```
goBack() {
  if (window.history.length > 1) {
    this.location.back()
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/home'])
  }
}
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

The problem with it is that some browsers (e.g. chrome) store initial page in the history, so `window.history.length > 1` and you will be sent to browser's initial page.

In my application I had to implement additional logic to determine where should user go in similar case.

```
goBack() {
  if (this.isHistory) {
    this.router.navigate(['/history'])
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/home'])
  }
}
```

Here's details on how to determine what was your previous URL: [How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)