# How to know previous URL even on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, web-frontend

I want my back button text (in Angular component) according to previous URL.

I have seen [How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular) but what if the user refreshes the page? The previous URL info from router events is lost. Any work around except storing it in the local storage?

Comment: If a user hits refresh than you need to store the URL somewhere, either in client side: localstorage, cookies or in server side: database, files system.

Comment: When you refresh your application the URL isn't lost. If it does in your application, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You can use HTML 5 `window.history` API to store route using `pushState` [See this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method)

Comment: Check [This](https://community.wia.io/d/22-access-the-previous-route-in-your-angular-5-app)