# ActivatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams is undefined

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-http-interceptors

There is a case, if I get Unauthorized Error(401), it should redirect the Login page which I have defined in my interceptor to handle this error. After login, it should redirect the previous page where I got the 401 error.

I have followed this tutorial, quite helpful to me: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/08/angular-2-redirect-to-previous-url-after-login-with-auth-guard.

But in the above tutorial, he didn't mention about redirection to login. So I have a question now, where should I store the route before the redirection to login. According to my knowledge, we cannot use the activatedRoute.snapshot in my interceptor.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the state of the @angular/route, read the documentation here:
https://angular.io/api/router

Then if it's an instance of NavigationEnd you can store it into the localStorage.
Answers and code samples are mentionned here:
[How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)