# On Angular Previous route is empty on button click

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to redirect the user to previous page when button is clicked following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular). I used the below line of code to get the previous route. When I print the prevURL on onInit method, it has value but when I tried to access the same value on button click it is empty. Is there any reason for it?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
    pairwise()
  ).subscribe((e: any) => {

    this.previousUrl = e[0].urlAfterRedirects;
  console.log(this.previousUrl);
});

}


BackToPrevRouteOnBtnClick(args) {
  console.log(this.previousUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can navigate user by

1. `this.router.navigate(['../'])`
2. `window.history.back()`
3. `window.history.go(-1)`
   But I recommend to you usage of #1

Is this working for you?

Comment: #1 is not working but #2 and #3 working. Is there any disadvantage of using #2 and #3?

Comment: yes when you use angular Universal for server side rendering

Comment: private _location: Location and this._location.back(); this also works.