# How to get the latest router where the user was in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the latest router (url) that the user has gone to and store it in local storage.
Anyone know a way to do this?
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can make use of **ActivatedRoute** class.

you can inject in your component like below and use some of its in-built methods.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

More info in angular docs https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute