# Get the previous and current URL in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to get the previous and current URL to set variables `prevUrl` and `currentUrl`  in Angular 8.
I have two components. `StudentComponent` and `HelloComponent` . 
When I navigate from `HelloComponent` to `StudentComponent`

In `StudentComponent` constructor `prevUrl` and `currentUrl` have value 
But when I clicked `showUrl` button then in console of browser show 
`prevUrl undefined` 
`currentUrl undefined`

How can I solve this problem? Why `prevUrl` and `currentUrl` in the constructor have value but in button doesn't value?

student component:

```
prevUrl:string;
currentUrl:string;
 constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.router.events
            .pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
            .subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
                this.prevUrl = events[0].urlAfterRedirects;
                this.currentUrl = events[1].urlAfterRedirects;
                console.log('this.prevUrl constructor', this.prevUrl);
                console.log('this.currentUrl constructor', this.currentUrl);
            });

 }
```

button:

```
showUrl = ()=>{

    console.log('prevUrl',this.prevUrl);
    console.log('currentUrl',this.currentUrl);
  }
```

### [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-event)

Comment: The code looks like its working, but you'll need to have that code in a service and not the component. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular.

Comment: Forked your stackblitz to show whats going on. Notice how the `subscribe event` never fires: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-get-the-previous-and-current-url-in-angular-8

Comment: `StudentComponent` is destroyed and recreated when the route changes. You need to move your logic to the `AppComponent` or a shared service so that code can listen for route changes.

Comment: @C_Ogoo Thanks. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866813/2585074) can help me

Comment: @Reactgular Thanks I add a service and used in StudentComponent and worked true.[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-event-and-service)

Answer (score 2):

Try like This :

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {        
        this.prevUrl = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
      };
 });
```

**Live Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-event-hr2xsc

Comment: in the console of browser show `prevUrl /student` ` currentUrl /student`. they are both alike