# how can i find paramter of previous route in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want find the params in previous route in angular typescript .

i use this code :

```
private previousUrl: string = undefined;
private currentUrl: string = undefined;

constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.previousUrl = event.url;
            this.currentUrl =  this.currentUrl;
        }
    });
}
```

but i can not access to the params of this url :

```
http://localhost:4200/claims-manager/200/edit
```

i want ti access `200` . how can i find params in url ????

Comment: Do you want the immediate previous route?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your component file but It is a best practice to do it in a service (using rxjs) to pass data and call it in your component file

**In your *service***

```
export class myService  {   
  constructor() { } 
  private param = new BehaviorSubject("");
  sharedParam = this.param.asObservable();


  paramToPass(param:string) { 
    this.param.next(param)}    
}
```

In your **component class that *set param***

```
export class ComponentSetParam  {
 param: string   
    constructor(private myService: Service)
  
 this.myService.setParam(this.param);
```

}

**in your *appModule***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [YourComponents]
  imports: [ AppRoutingModule, YourModules...],
  providers: [ShareService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Component that you want to *pass data***

```
export class ComponentGetParam  {
    paramFromService: string
    
     constructor(private myService: Service) {
       this.shareService.sharedData.subscribe(data : string => { 
         this.paramFromService = data;
     })
   }
  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
readonly _destroy$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) {
  this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        takeUntil(this._destroy$)
        )
      .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        const id = params.get('id');
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this._destroy$.next(true);
  this._destroy$.complete();
}
```

Where 'id' is a name, that you use in the routing, e.g.

```
path: '/claims-manager/:id/'
```

Comment: i want find id for previous route not current route

Comment: Look at the example, i use '.parent' for accessing for parent routing and params '200'.

Comment: If you want to get full previous route, look on this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)

Comment: wthat is this `this._destroy$`

Comment: This is unsubscriber. [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil)

Comment: i have tow page . 1 - list of items .  2- edit item   - - -  i want access to id in page 1 ( list of item ) . now i must use you code in page 1 or page 2 ?

Comment: Use this code - where you need this var('200'), in your case - it's on list of items.

Comment: i want when in list of items , click on one items , when got in the edit page and back into the list of items i can get the params (id) in list of items

Comment: Try to debug the 'params' var and look what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-neaozi) You can do it in service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class ShareService  {   
  constructor() { } 
  private paramSource = new BehaviorSubject("");
  sharedData = this.paramSource.asObservable();
  setParam(param:string) { this.paramSource.next(param)}    
}
```

in constructors

```
constructor(private shareService: ShareService)
```

in component in `ngOnDestroy` set this like  `this.shareService.setParam(param);`

in appmodule

```
  providers:[ShareService ]
```

in new component in ngOnInit or in constructor get like

```
 this.shareService.sharedData.subscribe(data=> { console.log(data); })
```