# How can I get the previous route as a path in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

How can I get the previous route as a path in Angular?

I tried using a solution via [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular), but it does not execute on first page load.

```
constructor(router: Router) {
  router.events
  .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
    console.log('prev:', event.previousUrl);
    this.previousUrl = event.url;
  });
}
```

I used both `RoutesRecognized` and `NavigationEnd`, however they did not work.

I called this method in the `constructor` and `ngOnInit`, but neither of them execute on first page load.

Is there any method of obtaining the previous URL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

In a constructor you can use

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().previousNavigation.finalUrl.toString()
```

to get the previous route path

Be careful if you use `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` outside a constructor it will be too late from life cycle and you will always have a null value

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().previousNavigation.finalUrl.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Router` class exposes a [`getCurrentNavigation()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L973-L975) method:

```js
getCurrentNavigation(): Navigation|null {
  return this.currentNavigation;
}
```

[`Router.currentNavigation`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L348) is of type `Navigation`:

```js
private currentNavigation: Navigation|null = null;
```

As we can see from `Navigation`'s definition, you can access the previous navigation with the [`previousNavigation`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L270) property:

```js
previousNavigation: Navigation | null;
```

So, you could use this property to get the previous path.

---

### Update

As [O.MeeKoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7952244/o-meekoh) suggested, `getCurrentNavigation()` must be called from the constructor.

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'previousNavigation' of null" when I use this.

Comment: @Dawid How are you using it?

Comment: Same here all of these properties are null or undefined for me. I access them from `ngOnInit` `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` | `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.previousNavigation`

Comment: This works, but it has to be inside of the constructor. If you update your answer you may get more upvotes.

Comment: Does this approach work with Angular 15?

Answer (score 0):

you can try navigationStart to resolve your problem of not getting the previous route for the first time.

you can refer the below lines of code for the getting the idea how to us that.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart )
      .bufferCount(2,1).subscribe(e => {
        if(e !== null && e !== undefined) this.orginalPath = e[0]['url'].substr(1)
    });
  }
```

Even you can try the method **pairwise()** if it resolves your problem.

```
router.events
  .pipe(
    filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
    pairwise() // check it's second route load
  )
  .subscribe((e: any[]) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Minal Shah....it tried your part ...but its not working at all...