# How to redirect to the previous page in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, window-object

I have a component to which the user can reach from various pages. When the user clicks an OK
button in this component, he should be redirected to the previous page ie. the page from where he
came to this component.

I came across **window.history.back();** and **this.router.navigate( '../' )**.

Also, what is the difference between window.history.back(); and this.router.navigate( '../' )

I also want to understand what's the difference between `this.location.back()` and `window.history.back()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the last successful navigation and navigate to it you can use:

```
const lastNav = router.getLastSuccessfulNavigation();

const previousRoute = lastNav.previousNavigation; 

router.navigateByUrl(previousRoute);
```

Note: Since `previousRoute` is of type `UrlTree` you can use it directly to navigate with the `navigateByUrl` method..

Regarding history.back (from the docs):

> The history.back() method causes the browser to move back one page in the session history. It has the same effect as calling history.go(-1) . If there is no previous page, this method call does nothing

While `this.router.navigate( '../' )` will lead you up to higher levels in the navigation using: `<a [routerLink]="['../', 'foo', 'bar']">Go Up</a>`

So the difference is that `window.history.back();` will lead you back and `this.router.navigate( '../' )` will lead you up..

Regarding your last question:

The `window` object refers to the current frame, which has a *history* object property that returns the history object for the window -> more Info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp

While `location` should be imported from `@angular/common` and used in a constructor like:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  // component's declarations here
})
class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private location: Location) 
  {}

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

The `goBack()` function can then be invoked by an `onClick` on a <kbd>Go Back</kbd> button for example..

Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components for more details..

Comment: Thanks @iLuvLogix !! I implemented and understood the difference.

Comment: Can you pls help me in understanding then what is this.location.back(). Is window.history.back() and location.back() same ?

Comment: @iLuvLogix, in what angular version is getLastSuccessfulNavigation() available in the router? I can't find it on 12.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on `getLastSuccessfulNavigation()` either. This worked for me though - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71296528/839639.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Location object

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common'; 
constructor(private location: Location){}
```

And use it when you need

```
this.location.back();
```