Figure out if history.back() stays within the same angular app
In Angular I would like to see if a history.back() would remain within the same app.
I can manually listen to route changes and keep a stack. Is there any way to get this information directly from the router?

you can only keep track of those within the app's domain.  URL's outside of that would not hit the router.  You might be able to know how many route changes have happened since the first load of the page, though.  What's the use-case?

I want a back button that just does history.back(). But it should be diabled, when it would jump out of the angular app.

Maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117070/how-can-i-get-the-previous-route-as-a-path-in-angular

@Jan please do not... Users gonna hate u for that
