# Know previous route Angular 7 [When using location.back()]

Tags: angular, routes, html5-history

I'm working on an Angular 7 app.

I use location.back() in a page/component A to go back to a previous page/component B.

What I want to know, is how to check in the component B logic that I'm coming from component A and not from another component, to use a specific behaviour in this case.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880387/7365461

Check out that answer and look at his Angular 6+ update, maybe it will help.