# How to get the previous page URL in angular 10

Tags: angular

How to get the previous page url in angular 10? I am trying to use the filter, pairwise and router RoutesRecognized originally mentioned in the below post

[How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)

First time it does not return any value and second onward it return and third time it returns the value 2 times and increment next time.

How to get the exact value from first time and should console only one time evrytime return in this page?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
        pairwise()
      ).subscribe((e: any) => {
        console.log(e[0].urlAfterRedirects); // previous url
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event instanceof NavigationEnd and create a service to persist the currentUrl and assign it back to previous url on any router NavigationEnd event.

I have created a Stackblitz with a quick demo of usecase: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw94et?file=src/app/app.component.html