# How to get previous route - route from where i came to current page

Tags: java, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

There are different ways through which I know the current route in angular.
I would like to know the previous route. Say for example I'm in a tab
`http://localhost:4200/test/testNav/ABC`.
Now, I click another tab that takes me to
`http://localhost:4200/test/SampleNav/XYZ`.

In the `ngOnInit()` method of this HTML "http://localhost:4200/test/SampleNav/XYZ" I want to get the previous URL which is /ABC.

`this.router.url`, `this.activatedRoute.snapshot` all gives me the currenturl.

Is there a way to get the previous URL from the available angular components?

Basically, when I come to XYZ page from ABC I should do something and when I come to XYZ from CBA I should do something else. Any inputs highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880387/7365461 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866813/7365461
Check out those links.\

Comment: @AliF50 From my point of view creating service for one previous url is little bit overkill in case of 1 or 2 time usage

Comment: I agree but the first link I posted doesn't have to be in a service, it can be in a component.

Comment: @AliF50. Thank you. how do i get the value of param from the redirect link say for example events[0].urlAfterRedirects gives me '/inventoryDetails;test=0;id=45', I want to get the value of id from this. How can i do without using subString

Comment: I wouldn't mind using `substring` for that but try logging out `events[0]` (console.log(events[0]) to see if you get a params object or anything of that sort that can give you extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes `getCurrentNavigation()` used with optional chaining (question mark) because it can be `null`. There you can take `previousNavigation` and `finalUrl` will return you an `UrlTree`. Next just execute navigation on `finalUrl` if it is not null.

```
const urlTree = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.previousNavigation?.finalUrl;
if (urlTree) { 
  this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
}
```