# Angular Activated Route - Fetch parent of url

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

I am using Angular 13 and need help with the Activated route. In short, I have 2 x routes:

```
/form/:id/:settings
/report/:id/:query
```

Whilst I know how to fetch the params such as :id, I am having trouble working out how to determine which route the url has taken that is report or form. Meaning is there a way to fetch the constants of a url pathway like 'form' or 'report'? I really only need the parent constant.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#router) service to get the entire URL so you can easily check if the path contains `form` or `report`

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){
  console.log(this.router.url);
}
```