# Only the current page can be accessed if it jumps from a specific page

Tags: angular

I have two pages. One is `/a` and the other is `/b`.

There is the a tag in the A page. It is `<a routerLink="b">B page</a>`.

My requirement is that users cannot directly access page B. they must click the a link from page A to access page B. how should I write my routing guard.

Comment: You would probably have to use [CanActivate guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) and check if the previous route was `/a`

Comment: @MrCodingB Yes, but I can't get the information of the previous route

Comment: Well if there's no way to access the previous route with the `RouterStateSnapshot` and the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`, you could subscribe to the activated routes or the router events in the guard and save the last route that way

Answer (score 1):

I think you could setup a service that would listen to `NavigationEnd` [events](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#router).  By doing this you could store previously activated url.

Then in the guard you'd just fetch previous url and check if it's `/a` or not.

Take a look at this example implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112335/9932919