# Unable to consistently determine previous route

Tags: angular

i am running into an issue where i am unable to determine the previous route / the page that called that component. I cant use the this.location.back() function as i need to pass some info back to the previous page, that's why i created the below service. It often works but many times it does not and claims the previous page is undefined. The issue seems to be often on the initial one when i start the app or reload browser, even then it should hit my URL service and know where i routed from which would be the home page.

My code for the service i am using looks like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class PreviousRouteService {

  private previousUrl: string;
  private currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;


    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
      .subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {

        this.previousUrl = events[0].urlAfterRedirects;
        console.log('previous url', this.previousUrl);
      });
  }

 
  public getPreviousUrl() {
    return this.previousUrl;
  }
}
```

And i call the Routes like this

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl(`/Farm/FarmMaster/${data.DocId}`, {
                state,
        });
```

And then to go back i call this

```
   goBack() {
        console.log('Will Route back to : ' + this.previousRouteService.getPreviousUrl())
        this.state$
            .pipe(
                takeWhile(_ => this.alive),
            )
            .subscribe(state => {
                console.log(state)
                this.router.navigate(['/'+this.previousRouteService.getPreviousUrl()]);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research i found the issue for me, i had to make sure the PreviousRouteService was loaded in the app.module

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private previousRouteService : PreviousRouteService){}
    
}
```

Credit to @Juliano https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866813/9860237