# Angular - How to determine which page came from?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

There are three pages. Page A, B, C. When I go to page A, I want to know which page I came from, page B or C?

I haven't been able to find a solution for several hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.events.forEach((event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

You can refer this thread for more info
[How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)