# How to get the previous page URL in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm working with Angular 5 app and I need to know how to get the last URL to place it as a link to my back button. I found this `location.back()` but what I need the last url as a string. How could I get the string that generates `location.back()`?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41039092/9775003)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine previous page URL in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular 6 updated code for getting previous url as string.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor (
        public router: Router
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events
            .pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
                pairwise()
            ).subscribe((e: any) => {
                console.log(e[0].urlAfterRedirects); // previous url
            });
    }
```

Comment: This is not working in angular 9, When first time I open my page, it won't return previous url, when second time I open my page, that time it return previous url, can you please give me suggestion for this, I have use same code in ngOnInit

Answer (score 1):

In the browser environment, `location.back()` is wrapper around the `window.history` object (for a partial path through the source, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/common/src/location/location.ts#L126), [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/common/src/location/hash_location_strategy.ts#L87), [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/common/src/location/platform_location.ts#L17) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter.ts#L362)).

The contents within the History object are purposefully not accessible.

From the [HTML History interface documention](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#the-history-interface):

> The actual entries are not accessible from script.

From [MDN the window.history object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history):

> For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the
>   non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session
>   history, but it does allow it to navigate the session history.

---

As to an alternate approach, [this answer provides a technique for listening for the last 2 NavigationEnd events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287471/373815).

Comment: Ok, But how could I implement in code what I want in angular 5?