# Angular2 getting string value from a route child

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need set the header title from child route view...
I have the parent component:

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'parent-component',
        template: `
<header>{{headerTitle}}</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    @RouteConfig([
        { path: '/link1', name: 'Link1', component: Link1Component, useAsDefault: true },
        { path: '/link2', name: 'Link2', component: Link2Component },
    ])

    export class ParentComponent {

        public sharedHeaderTitle: string;
        constructor(public router: Router) { }

    }
```

Have a childs routing tabs:

```
@Component({
    template: '<div></div>'
})

export class Link1Component {
    public headerTitle: string;
    constructor() {
        this.headerTitle = "Link1 page";
    }
}
```

and another one

```
@Component({
    template: '<div></div>'
})

export class Link2Component {
    public headerTitle: string;
    constructor() {
        this.headerTitle = "Link2 page";
    }
}
```

How it make in parent-childs I found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) but its not working with routing...
What is best way to make it?

---

### **SOLVED**

I found one solution, think it's the best way:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LYTXmY9Fwm8LwumICWDT

Answer (score 0):

`Link1Component` and `Link2Component` need to communicate to `ParentComponent`. Since they are confined in a router-outlet I am not sure whether this is possible other than subscribing to a router event (see [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/angular-2-0-how-to-detect-route-change))

I would also consider to change a bit the design and move the responsibility of setting the title to the `ParentComponent`, i.e. the `ParentComponent` sets the title before issuing the `router.navigate(['LinkXComponent']` command.

I hope this helps