# Typescript instanceof - Cannot find name

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a problem with Typescript compilation. This code returns the error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NavigationEnd'.

How can I make the compiler know about NavigationEnd type? NavigationEnd is angular2 router event type.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {e instanceof NavigationEnd ? 
console.log('NavigationEnd'):console.log('Not NavigationEnd')});
```

I`m using IDE PHPStorm.

Comment: Did you import it from `@angular/router`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you.

Comment: Weird. Everything else auto imports with VS Code's intellisense, but `NavigationEnd` won't? Things like `ActivatedRoute` and `Router` were imported into `@angular/router`, but I had to type `NavigationEnd` in manually.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems you're missing an import

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'
```

Comment: Why is Angular2 encourage/forcing this anti-pattern on developers? What value is there in using `instanceof` to test an Event type?

Comment: I don't use TS myself (only Dart) and in Dart and other languages I know this is no antipattern. Perhaps filter like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657 is a bit of an improvment.

Comment: In JavaScript it is a very confusing pattern because it looks like it does in other languages, but it doesn't even have the same kinds of operands.

Java : `x instanceof T` -> `x` is a value and `T` is a type;
JavaScript : `x instanceof T` -> `x` is a value and `T` is a value;

It also couples you to an implementation detail, why should I care that it has a specific prototype?

Answer (score 4):

I did a small test and it seems that you might have forgotten to include "NavigationEnd" as an import to your project. (Like günter hinted at in the comments)

`import { NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';`

After including this, TypeScript no longer complained about it being missing ;-)