# How can i set the redirect if ionViewCanEnter return false on ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3

How should I set the redirect to the LoginPage in the case of invalid authentication

In angular4, I set the redirect by guards on the router

But ionic3 is no router, If set up in MyApp constructor, this can only take effect at initialization, and can not come into effect when the user is later logged out or when the authentication is invalid. This solution is not suitable for me.
So I saw NavController, I returned to false in `ionViewCanEnter()`, ionic is successfully intercepted the request, but it is redirected to a blank page, I want to send this blank page is set to LoginPage, I tried `navCtrl.push()`, and `navCtrl.setRoot()` in `ionViewCanEnter` , if the function return false is not correct redirect, it still remain in the blank page

How can i set the redirect if invalid authentication

Comment: @Geerson May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39971274/7561290) can be helpful to track page change event in ionic 2+.

Comment: extends can help me to implement the same function on different pages. If I do authentication in `viewDidLoad ()`, 

then redirect to LoginPage or stay on current page, which is also a feasible method. But if this is done, the 

redirect to the LoginPage will  transient stay on current page before redirect . It doesn't seem to be the best 

solution.

Comment: are you sure that navCtrl.setRoot() does not work? I have something like this implemented in my `ionViewCanEnter` and seems to work as expected:
`ionViewCanEnter() {
    if(!this.isLoggedIn())
      this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('FBLoginPage');
  }`

Comment: did you ever found a solution on it. Not sure which version is useing @Seb92 but from version 3.5.x, if I'm not wrong, there is a breaking change! You can not redirect to lazy loaded page if ionViewCanEnter returns false.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('UnauthorizedPage');
});
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('LoginPage');
}, 200);
```