# How to detect URL change in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Route change can be detected using the `router.events` stream. ([How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2)).

But I am not sure how to detect browser URL change.

Comment: Browser URL change can only be caused by 2 factors: Route change inside Angular2 or user manually type in new URL. You can subscribe to the former. The latter will reload the whole application and detecting it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The later case could also be coming from user clicking other external URL, or clicking on their browser's bookmarks bar. In my application, I need to catch this to present an Unsaved Changes confirmation dialog to user.

Answer (score 4):

Inject `Location` and use the `onUrlChange` event listener:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) {
  location.onUrlChange(url => console.log(url));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can inject [`Location`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html#!#subscribe-anchor) and subscribe to it

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

...

constructor(location:Location) {
  location.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

As Harry mentioned. This only notifies about popState events (the router or similar code changing the URL)

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't any built-in way to catch all URL change then. not like: `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', () => {...})` in angular 1

Comment: please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2

Comment: `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Location'.`

Comment: That was changed AFAIR. `BrowserLocation` has it, but that was made private. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate should work or if you use the Angular router, it allows to subscribe to changes as well (see link in the question).

Comment: I was getting "Property subscribe does not exist.." because I missed the correct import: `import {Location} from '@angular/common';`

Answer (score 2):

***You can achieve to subscribe to router events from your root file like this***

```
constructor(private router: Router,
          private aRouter: ActivatedRoute) {
this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
.subscribe((s: NavigationEnd) => {
  //write your logic here
   console.log(s);
});
}
```