# Subscribe to child route changes in master/detail example in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem with routing in a master/detail view. If i go to the route `/master` the `InfoComponent` should show some general info. And if I go to `/master/1` the `DetailsComponent` should show some data for the item with id 1. In both cases, `MasterComponent` should show either the selected id or nothing.

I can get this working fairly well. But the problem is that I want to subscribe to the selected `:id` in `OnInit` in `MasterComponent` so that I can highlight it there, something like this:

```
this.selectedId = this.route.params.map((params: Params) => params["id"])
```

But that doesn't work since `:id` is a child route param. And I can't use `this.route.firstChild` since firstChild will be another route depending on if `InfoComponent` or `DetailsComponent` is showing.

Can I get an observable (of `:id`) that changes when `MasterComponent` changes between showing the two child components?

This is my routing module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: "master",
                canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        component: MasterComponent,
                        children: [
                            {
                                path: "",
                                component: InfoComponent
                            },
                            {
                                path: ":id",
                                component: DetailsComponent
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class MyRoutingModule { }
```

So what I would like is to do something like:

```
this.selectedId = this.route.params.map((params: Params) => params["id"])
```

Where `this.selectedId` is an `Observable` that has the value `1` if the route is `/master/1` or the value `null` if the route is `/master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
this.route.firstChild.params.map(...)
```

or use a shared service to communicate the params changes from the child to the parent. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service for examples.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, `firstChild` doesnt really work, since it will be different depending on which of the child components that are active. I was hoping that I would somehow be able to subscribe to changes when the url changes from `/master/1` to `/master` in the `MasterComponent`. So I can't really do that without involving logic in the child components? That's a bummer... :/

Comment: You can get the information from `firstChild` what component is actually add it and ignore the param changes for components you're not interested in.

Comment: I'll set up a plunker to describe what I mean :)

Comment: This official plunker from the angular.io guide to routing is actually quite descriptive. http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview. In `CrisisListComponent` they do `this.route.params.forEach` but that will never contain a value for `params["id"], even if the initial URL is `/crisis-center/1` (which is a bit hard to test through the plunker though). Should this be considered a bug in the router or should `params["id"]` only be accessible from the component that matches that url..?

Comment: I have edited that plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/4eijIs62dyDyI6LkJZZl?p=preview. Here I subscribe to `firstChild` instead to update `selectedId`. It doesn't work since in `ngOnInit` the first child is the `CrisisCenterHomeComponent`. It would work if I could have navigated directly to '/crisis-center/1` (which I don't know how to do in a plunker..)

Do you see what I mean?

Comment: This might work for you http://plnkr.co/edit/EZv0Xm7BkFyPs61MFeNv?p=preview (my code changes are in the constructor of `app/crisis-center/crisis-list.component.ts` only)

Comment: Ok. Yes, that might be what I have to do then. The problem with that is that I get all router events, application wide, but that should be easy to fix by using a more strict check in the `if`. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `filter()` to get nicer code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657