# How to troubleshoot routing in nativescript angular?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm just learning nativescript, angular and typescript. I'm developing for iOS using the simulator. My routing is configured like so (copy-pasted from the NativeScript inspector):

```
config: Array (7)
0{path: "filtered/:topic/:queryText", component: function}
1{path: "abstract/:id", component: function}
2{path: "session/:id", component: function}
3{path: "details/:id", component: function}
4{path: "home", component: function}
5{path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full"}
6{path: "**", redirectTo: "home"}
```

Routing from `home` to `details` uses this code in the `home.component`:

```
showDetails(e){
    console.log(e.index);
    this.router.navigate(["details", e.index]);
}
```

This works most of the time, but reliably fails when I first navigate to the `filtered` component, and then return using the Back button. The `showDetails` function fires, logging the correct value for `e.index`, but the the app does not route to `details`; The `home` page does not change at all (but I can still navigate to other pages from the `home` page).

My question is, how should I troubleshoot this? I can see the `this.router` object in the inspector, but it's a very complex object with what looks like hundreds of nested properties. I'm guessing I should try and figure out what `this.router` looks like when the `showDetails` function works as expected, and how it changes when `showDetails` no longer works. But what properties should I focus on? Or should I be looking at something else?

Many thanks for any tips or guidance.

UPDATE: the problem occurs whenever I navigate to more than two other pages, e.g., if I just navigate to `filtered`, it doesn't occur, but if navigate from `filtered` to `abstract`, and then use the back button twice, it always occurs. Same if first navigate to `session` and then `abstract`, and then back to `home`.

UPDATE 2: Answers here are very helpful for debugging routing:

[How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2)

UPDATE 3: I figured it out. One of the parameters in my routes was sometimes empty, leading to a url with a double slash: `/filtered//search-term`. Angular doesn't seem to like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for routing.

**app-routing.module.ts :-**

```
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: "home", loadChildren: "~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule" },
{ path: "details/:id", loadChildren: "~/app/details/details.module#DetailsModule" },
{ path: "session/:id", loadChildren: "~/app/session/session.module#SessionModule" }
```

**For Redirect to page :-**

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

constructor(private zone: NgZone,
private _routerExtensions: RouterExtensions){ }

gotoStartPage() {
 setTimeout(() => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
     this._routerExtensions.navigate(["details", 2], {
        clearHistory: (isIOS) ? true : false,
     });
    });
  }, 500);
}
```