# ngOnInit with numeric routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a **component** that I need to be rendered for numeric routes like **/1, /2, /3** etc
(where number is :id).

In my component I've declared **ngOnInit** code

```
ngOnInit(){
   alert();
}
```

When **first** time route changes alert fires, **but for other route changes it doesn't**. I'm wondering why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the `id` parameter from the `params` observable in the `ActivatedRoute` service.You can do this as follows :

//Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute      
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params['id']);
    // alert();
  });
}
```

Comment: That works great - Thanks! I have one question - if I remove comment from alert in your code and if my route (let's say) is /5 or /10 or whatever. When I refresh page using F5 button it says "ReferenceError: alert is not defined"

Comment: `alert` is not part of JavaScript, it's part of the `window` object provided by web browsers so i think it doesn't exist in inside `subscribe` context and because of it its not working

Answer (score 1):

If the component is already loaded you should subscribe to changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548895/2013580

```
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        // see also 
        console.log(val instanceof NavigationEnd) 
    });
  }
```