# Issue with Router event

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following piece of code:

```
 this.routerSubscription = this._router.events
     .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
     .subscribe((event:Event) => {
        ....
     });
```

Which throws me an error of:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | NavigationCancel | NavigationError> | ErrorObserve...'.
  Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | NavigationCancel | NavigationError) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'event' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | NavigationCancel | NavigationError' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
        Type 'NavigationStart' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
          Property 'bubbles' is missing in type 'NavigationStart'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21):

I guess you forgot about:

```
import { Event } from '@angular/router';
```

Or use it like:

```
import { Event as NavigationEvent } from '@angular/router';
...
.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent)
```

See also

- [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the solution wasn't about importing the `Event` interface.
Instead, the key was to utilize a TypeScript type guard to explicitly inform the TypeScript compiler about the type of `event` once it passes through the `filter` function of RxJS.

using your code as an example:

```js
 this.routerSubscription = this._router.events
     .filter((event) : event is NavigationStart => event instanceof NavigationStart)
     .subscribe((event) => {
        // Your logic here...
     });
```

Notice how we surrounded the event argument with parentheses and added the type guard (`(event): event is NavigationStart`).
This way, the Typescript compiler understands that if the arrow function returns `true`, `event` is guaranteed to be of type `NavigationStart`.
With the type guard in place, TypeScript will treat event as `NavigationStart` within the `subscribe` method.