# Can't access RouterStateSnapshot properties on Angular custom Directive

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

I'm coding a custom Directive that change the background-image style property according to the activated route.

To achieve this functionality, i try to reach the `url` property of `RouterStateSnapshot`, and manipulate the element's style according to `url`'s value.

I'm logging to the console just for test.

Here's the code.

```
import { Directive, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterState, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[bgImg]'
})
export class BgImgDirective {

  constructor(
    private _renderer: Renderer,
    private _router: Router
  ) {

    var state: RouterState = this._router.routerState;
    var stateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot = state.snapshot;
    var url: any = stateSnapshot.url;

    console.log(url);
  }

}
```

- `console.log(url);` **prints nothing to the console.**
- The `url` variable is always empty

This is my root **app.component** template

```
<div bgImg>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**However**

If i try `console.log(this._router);`

This is the result:

[image: Console output]

How can I get to the value of `url` on different states of the Router, and properly apply an if statement to these? Do i have to make use of Observables?

Comment: Hard to tell. Perhaps you get the root router instead of the router for the segment that you actually want. It depends on where your directive is applied.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, i updated my question with the code in app.component.html

Comment: You are trying to get it like router.routerState instead of router.currentRouterState..

Comment: This means you always get the root router. Try ti subsribe to router events and get the url from the event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657

Comment: @DenkoMancheski, if i try `this._router.currentRouterState`, i get a typescript error `Property 'currentRouterState' is private and only accessible within class 'Router'`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks!! Your answer worked perfectly. If you post your answer here i'll mark it as solved by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to router events and get the URL from there

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.forEach((event) => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  });
}
```

see also [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657)

Answer (score 1):

This [answer by Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657) put me on the right way to achieve what I was looking for. Here's the code:

```
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Directive({
 selector: '[BgImg]'
})
export class BgImgDirective {

constructor(
 private _elRef: ElementRef,
 private _renderer: Renderer,
 private _router: Router
) {
_router.events
 .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
 .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
  switch(event.url) {
   case "/":
    _renderer.setElementStyle(_elRef.nativeElement, "background-image", "url('../path/to/img')");
   break;
   case "/other-page":
    _renderer.setElementStyle(_elRef.nativeElement, "background-image", "url('../path/to/img')");
   break;
   }
  });
 }
}
```