# Angular 2 get previous page url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have two components. Customer and Shipment components. When user come from Shipment component to Customer component. I want to Customer component direct to Shipment component.

I use this method. 
`this._location.back();` from Location angular/common.

This method every always direct to back page. But I want direct to just when i came from shipment component.

Comment: You can use `pairwise` like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657 and store the current and previous value in a service

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATED for Angular 6**

Insert the code below to your parent component, which contains your 2 components:-

```
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from "@angular/router";
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';

previousUrl:string;

constructor(private router: Router) {

    router.events
        .pipe(
          filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized),
          pairwise()
        )            
        .subscribe((e: any) => {
            this.previousUrl = e[0].urlAfterRedirects;
        });
}
```

It worked for me, I hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: add this code to your parent component, which contains your 2 components

Comment: i added pairwise method to code. It returns two url current and previous. But i didnt use these urls anywhere.

Comment: You can subscribe to route changes & store the current event so you can use it when the next happens.And it depends on what you expect. in initially(1st time) it's value will be null, because there is no previous route. You also need to do this on the root router, otherwise, you'll only get when you navigate between child routes of this component.

Comment: Got error  Property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'.

Comment: This answer should never have been accepted, and it should probably be deleted. This only returns the current route, this does not return the previous url as suggested.

Comment: This answer is not providing required result - answer should be improved or explained in a better way

Comment: @SandeepChikhale I have updated the answer for version >6

Comment: The Angular 6 one didnt work for me. It returns nothing.