# Security Error in angular 2 application routing on using browser authentication in the URL

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, angular2-routing

I am running into a problem with my angular 2 application on using the URL with browser authentication credentials. If I load the URL without the credentials, it works as expected.

But if I trigger the URL in the format:

https://username:password@[REST_OF_URL], the different page sections are not loading withe such errors being thrown in the console:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): **SecurityError:** The operation is
>   insecure.

I am currently checking it in FireFox version 52.

I debugged, and the issue appears to be due to failure in the routing mechanism when authentication credentials are used.

I followed the router event tracking as suggested here:

[How to detect a route change in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657.)

The `NavigationStart` and `RoutesRecognized` events are triggered as expected with correct resolution of routes. After this, `NavigationError` is triggered with the error mentioned above:

> **SecurityError:** The operation is insecure.

How shall I address this? Any known issues to address with routing when using authentication credentials?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm getting the same error