# update DOM or refresh component in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

How to refresh a component/page in angular 2?.
 I used routing to current URL. I don't know, it is not working properly.

How do I update DOM component when I redirect to same URL(where I was working) while routing?

Comment: I don't understand your question properly. What do want to achieve? Just reloading a components data? Reload the whole site? Why?

Comment: i just want to detect changes and update Dom elements when i click refresh button.

Comment: i am using breadcrumb . while redirecting to previous page it's not loading properly . that's my actual situation

Comment: Well, now we're closer. Can you share your breadcrumb code?

Comment: My first guess to solve this problem would be subscribing to route changes. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2 This way you don't have to mess with event handling and reloading page.

Comment: In Breadcrumb i have refresh button . While click on the button, i need to refresh page/update DOM elements (current URL). I mean refreshing current URL when i click the button. That's it . But it is not working!..

Comment: You Know it is redirecting but corresponding page is not showing all elements. So i need to refresh/update component.

Comment: Wow, I thought I know what you what, but now im more confused than before. Can you provide code, screenshots, whatever?