# How to change the body background or background-color on route change angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to change the body background or background-color on route change, angular 4?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I need to change the background color from the main index.html when I route to home component or dashboard component

Comment: That's your *requirement*, not what you've *actually tried*. Please note that SO is not a code-writing or tutorial service; take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Code is text, **post it as such**. Screenshots are useless. Give a [mcve], and spend some more time reviewing the material in the [help]. Ensure that you're demonstrating actual research effort, not just more detail on what you want other people to implement for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to listen for the route change event, which should be [`NavigationEnd`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd), also may want to [`check this post out`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2) and do something like:

```
document.body.style.background = '#000' // or whatever color
```

Comment: so even though this question has been answered I should copy that answer into here?

Comment: You could propose it as a duplicate, and let the OP spend some figuring out how to adapt it to their specific needs.