# How to set onhashchange in angular component

Tags: angular, lifecycle

I am not able to set **onhashchange** property using angular 4, i tried to set onhashchange in the following life cycle of the angular 4 but it is not working.

**ngAfterContentInit**

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    //disabling browser back button
    window.location.hash = "lienholder-details";
    window.location.hash = "Again-lienholder-details";//again because google chrome don't insert first hash into history
    window.onhashchange = function () { window.location.hash = "lienholder-details"; }
  }
```

**ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit(){
 //disabling browser back button
        window.location.hash = "lienholder-details";
        window.location.hash = "Again-lienholder-details";//again because google chrome don't insert first hash into history
        window.onhashchange = function () { window.location.hash = "lienholder-details"; }
}
```

how to set the onhashchange property in angular 4

Answer (score 2):

```
@HostListener('window:hashchange', ['$event'])
hashChangeHandler(e) {
  window.location.hash = "lienholder-details";
}
```

or if you are using the router

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.forEach((event) => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  });
}
```

(see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080657/217408)

Comment: i have a home component and a display component, i want to deactivate the back button only in the display component not on the home component, how can i do it

Comment: I'd try checking the URL and if it points to the display component, and then call `e.preventDefault();` (not verified if this works)

Comment: dont the angular 4 has a lifecycle which will run after all the window loads gets completed?

Comment: Not sure why you think that is related to the problem, and no, Angular doesn't have something like that. There is no clear point when "everything is loaded".

Comment: ok thanks i actually tried the ngAfterViewChecked event and it is working, thanks for your help

Comment: `ngAfterViewChecked` might be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I used ngAfterViewChecked event and i am able to set onhashchange property