# change data on route event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, components

How to change data in one component relatively to others on route event in Angular?

For e.g. if I have three components: `"nav.component"`, `"about.component"` and `"service.component"`.

So I want to display different text in `"nav.component"` when I switch between `about` and `service` pages in my app.

My `"app.router.ts"` file:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ServiceComponent } from './service/service.component';

export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'service', component: ServiceComponent }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

I don't want to display just page name text in my nav bar while switching between these pages, it would be a custom text for each component.
Also I would like to store this data/text directly in `"about.component.ts"` and `"service.component.ts"` but not in the `"app.router.ts"` due to maintainability and scalability.

Is it possible?

**U.P.D.**

This is my `"app.component.html"` file:

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Nav Bar (text changes here) -->
  <app-nav></app-nav>

  <!-- Pages (components which are included in app.router.ts) -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

For e.g. this is `"about.component.ts"` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  const text_for_nav_bar = "This is my new About page."; // <-- text that should be displayed in nav component for this page on router event.

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. What is nav.component? How is your application structured? What do you mean by custom text? Where do you want to display it? All this information is required to answer your question.

Comment: u can do that with route change events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2

Comment: @VinodBhavnani, I've updated my post, hope this will help. I want to store custom text string for each component and this string should be displayed in `nav` component depending on router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below code you will able to subscribe router change events. You need to add this code on nav bar.

Import router and Navigation start

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import "rxjs/add/operator/pairwise";
```

Add below code in constrictor.

```
this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
  .pairwise()
  .subscribe((value: [NavigationStart, NavigationStart]) => {
     let nextUrl = value[1].url;
     if (nextUrl == '/about') {
         // your code here for next url
     }
  },
    (err) => {

    },
    () => { });
}

});
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is an error occurs: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'`

Comment: Thanks! Now it compiles well but `nextUrl` doesn't contain a string when I'am trying to put `{{ nextUrl  }}` into my template :(

Comment: make nextUrl global variable in this case.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But how to store text data in page components and get them on route event in nav bar component?

Comment: make it pablic static or store them into localstorage and access

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with `*ngIf` (or `[hidden]` if you want to load all contents to the DOM at once). And to catch current route, inject Router module:

```
class NavComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router){

    }
}
```

and in nav.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/some/route'">
 text for this route
</div>
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/other/route'">
 text for other route
</div>
```

Doing same in component.ts, could be:

nav.component.html:

```
<h1>{{yourText}}</h1>
```

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(this.router.url == '/some/route') {
    yourText = 'Text'
  } elseif(this.router.url == '/other/route') {
    yourText = 'Other text'
  }
}
```

Comment: now I think that might be needed to trigger Change Detection and use other cycle hook. If it doesnt work, plese let me know. Its been a while I've done something with Angular

Comment: I've just checked out your example above, unfortunately it doesn't work. `this.router.url` doesn't return a path, just one slash only.

Comment: So its probably returns the root path. But it never changes while navigating, because navComponent was initialised only once. Subscribing to Router events is the right way, as @Shabbir Dhangot wrote, just I am not guarantied about his logic (I forgot Angular a bit)

Comment: All in all, `*ngIf` with `router.url` works well, but slightly improper for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use router datas

```
export const router: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'about', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: {navigationText: 'Some text'} },
    { path: 'service', component: ServiceComponent, data: {navigationText: 'Some other text'} }
];
```

and in app.component.html

```
<div class="container">

    <app-nav text="outlet.activatedRouteData.navigationText"></app-nav>

    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>

</div>
```

Of course you need to add a "@Input text: string" property in nav.component.ts