# Angular4 import service containing only event handler methods compilation error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular service that is just supposed to monitor for route changed events. When I try to add this service at the AppModule level I get a compilation error that says something like "Service is declared but its value is never read'. I understand what the error means and get why its popping up, the issue is that I don't need to call any of the service functions from outside the service. Here is a snippet similar to what I have going on for my Service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .forEach(e => this.onRouteChanged(this.route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data.analytics.pageName));
  }
  onRouteChanged(pageName: string) {
    // do some stuff with the page name
  }
}
```

This is what I have in my app.module.ts. If I don't include the ngOnInit function that just does a console log with my service then it will fail to compile.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService // if this line is not here then my service doesn't load at all and the route changed event is not tracked
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myService);
  }
}
```

If I do the console.log I can see the route changed event firing so I know the service gets loaded. Is it possible to do include the MyService reference without requiring the console.log?

Comment: You could change this to `public myService: MyService`

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You said it works, but I can't see how. You are not subscribing to the route events. Something like this makes more sense to me:

```
this.router.events
  .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .map(e => this.route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data.analytics.pageName)
  .subscribe(this.onRouteChanged)
```

This other code is necessary to angular creates an instance of your service

```
constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) { }
```

I just tried a test here and I didn't need this `console.log(this.myService)` for it to work. Maybe if you provide more information.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Angular 4 so not quite sure how its working. I am inheriting this app from another team and I can't post the exact source code here. I will try to make an sample app that shows the issue. Do you know if its possible to have that "private myService: MyService" in the code without having to reference any of the service functions?

Comment: I did some more research and noticed in the first answer of this post I linked does it the same way as my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular