# Detect navigation back from component in named router outlet

Tags: angular, router-outlet, ngoninit

I display an **A Component** in a router-outlet and inside this I have another **B Component** which has a named router-outlet, where I display another **C component**.

```
Router-outlet
A Component
    B Component
    Named Router-outlet
        C Component
```

In this **C Component**, I perform a validation, after this, I want to go back into the **A Component** reloading it (executing ngOnInit or any method).

I have tried it using different methods, like navigate, navigateByUrl and Location.back(). The problem is that the **A Component** is never destroyed, therefore it's never executed the ngOnInit method.

Somebody know how can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you'll be able to execute the ngOnInit again, but a workaround could be to subscribe to router events (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular)) and execute the code you want in there.

Comment: thanks! It worked... I didn't know about router events.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service to handle this specific situation

```
   export class RefreshService{   
       private refreshMessage = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);        
       refreshObservable = this.refreshMessage.asObservable();

       sendRefreshMessage() {
         this.refreshMessage.next("");
       }
    }
```

In component A I subscribe to my observable

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private refreshService: RefreshService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.refreshService.subscribe(res => { do stuff here } );
  }

}
```

In component C after you perform your validation :

```
this.refreshService.sendRefreshMessage();
```

This will trigger your subscription in component A, all code inside the subscription will then be executed

Comment: Thanks! This also worked but I think is cleaner the solution proposed by @Lars. If you have any comment let me know. Thanks again!