# How to load the nested component as default in the child component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like to set the default component for my child component. how to do that?
here is my router.ts

```
{
        path: 'cpServices',
        component: CpServiceComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'contentPlaceholder',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'contentPlaceholder', //child has outlet
                component: ShellContentPlaceholderComponent,
                children : [
                    {
                        path: 'create', //need as default
                        component: ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
```

**Addition Request**

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <header-nav-shell></header-nav-shell>
    <div class="main-section">
        <div class="content-left"> //some times need to hide this, how?
            <side-nav-shell></side-nav-shell>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a wildcard for empty space to redirect to default component

```
{
        path: 'cpServices',
        component: CpServiceComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'contentPlaceholder',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'contentPlaceholder', //child has outlet
                component: ShellContentPlaceholderComponent,
                children : [
                    {
                        path: 'create', //need as default
                        component: ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent
                    },
                    {
                     path: '', // 
                     redirectTo: 'create',
                     pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
```

or this way by set the redirectTo to the `ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent` like this

```
{
        path: 'cpServices',
        component: CpServiceComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'contentPlaceholder/create', // 
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'contentPlaceholder', //child has outlet
                component: ShellContentPlaceholderComponent,
                children : [
                    {
                        path: 'create', //need as default
                        component: ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent
                    }

                ]
            }

        ]
    }
```

Comment: yes, works. can  you see `Addition Request` in my question part? do you have any idea about it? some component side navi not requried

Comment: in that case you need to create aglobal service and emit a value on the ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent ngOninit method , you need to create a basic comunication between components

Comment: can't i do with sending router data?

Comment: it can be work but you need to get this `ShellContentPlaceholderComponent` and `ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent` both will be loaded so it 's better to emit a value `ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent ` in init and destroy

Comment: you can check the router event can be a better way in her e   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular