# How to run a function when a route changes in angular?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

I want to change a certain heading according to the current url in Angular. So component.ts looks like this:

```js
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
//code
public name: string
constructor(
    public router: Router
  ) {}
getName()
{
if(this.router.url === "/some_list")
{this.name = "List"}
else if(this.router.url === "/detail")
{this.name = "Detail"}
}
```

And then

```html
<a>{{this.name}}</a>
```

The existing answers, like [How to detect a route change in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043) could not tell me how to do something after a change in routing (change = true or false). 
So how can I run this function whenever the url changes, so that the heading is according to the current view?

Comment: Refer this one https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can `subscribe` to `router event` in the `app.component.ts`.
It will fire every time you change the `route`.

```
  constructor(location: Location, router: Router) {
    // decide what to do when this event is triggered.
    router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (location.path() != "/something") {
          // do something
      } else {
         // do something else
      }
    });
  }
```

---

Try this if it is calling multiple times

```
router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(val => { // here your code... })
```

**Note: I have not tried this**

---

Comment: This will get called multiple times for all the different events. Check log.

Answer (score 7):

Go this [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vizvyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

On every navigation start event of router you can get url and fire function. in you app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.router.events.subscribe(event =>{
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart){
         console.log(event.url)
         this.routerChangeMethod(event.url);
      }
   })
}

routerChangeMethod(url){
  this.title = url;
}
```

Yout app.component.html is..

```
{{title}}

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fire for me when I change routes. Only once when I refresh the app.

Answer (score 2):

As a good practice you should have [one component per route](https://angular.io/guide/router).

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'products', component: DetailComponent },
    { path: 'shopping-cart', component: SomelistComponent }
])
```

If you keep to this practice, then you will have a separation of concern.

And then according to the route you just set header for your component.

You can read more about [routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) here.

Comment: I totally agree - I have already one component per rule, but I have an extra component for the contenttab to navigate between these components - and for a special use cas of this contenttabs I need the headings

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-gxv5fc?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

.html

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/some_list">Home</a> |
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/detail">Catalog</a>

<router-outlet (activate)="getName()"></router-outlet>
```

.ts

```
getName() {
  if (this.router.url.includes("some_list")) {
      this.name = "some_list";
  } else if (this.router.url.includes("detail")) {
      this.name = "detail";
  }
  alert(this.name);
}
```

Comment: I think I read that its bad practice to use methods in the markup. These methods will be called a lot of times during the render phases. Check answer from GaurangDhorda below instead

Answer (score 1):

After observing some issues in the comment I thought I should post this as an alternative solution if it helps someone. We will cater 2 issues in this solution:

1. Handling contents based on the route.
2. Avoiding multiple checking of the same function

For that, instead of using `OnInit` it is better to handle it in the constructor as it is better and will be checked earlier.

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // handle NavigationEnd event here
      console.log(event.url);
    }
  });
}
```